# How to download a file from a URL that requires a 'Bearer Token' from the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt, openurl

I have the URL for a file but it is protected and requires a JWT token.

This won't work.

```rb
require 'open-uri'
open('image.png', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open('http://example.com/image.png').read
end
```

Is there a way to pass headers on that request?

Comment: yes, it's in the docs here https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a header in the second parameter as described in https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html.

```
require 'open-uri'

token = "f00"

url = "http://via.placeholder.com/150"

open('image.png', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open(url, "Authorization" => "Bearer #{token}").read
end
```